# Run a command, when a player has turned a certain page in a book

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want an command to be executed in **minecraft 1.15.2 [Java-Edition]** when a player has turned a certain page in a book. I am currently using the following command for this in a **repeating command** block that is **always active**.

```
execute if entity @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:written_book",tag:{pages:["generator"]}}}] run say You opened the page with the word "generator"!
```

However, this command does not work and there is no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Books don't store the currently looked-at page. As far as I know, it's not even known to the server which page you look at.

If you want to trigger something when a player turns to a page in a book, you need a lectern. And then you can simply use a comparator or read the `Page` tag in NBT.

Comment: From what I understand, that's never been the case. The command searches for a specific word [in this case "generator"] and as soon as this word is present on the opened page, a command is to be triggered.The word can appear on different pages, but the first page that is opened with this word triggers the command.

Comment: No, you can only check whether any page with the exact content "generator" (and nothing else) exists anywhere in the book. And even that is complicated, because of [this oversight](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-139625). [This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/361957/171580) tells you how to work around it. But that only lets you check whether that text is a page either anywhere in the book or on a specific page, but it doesn't tell you whether that's opened. Minecraft has no string manipulation, like search, substrings, concatenation, etc.